# Expected Value of an Infinite Sum of Random Poisson Variables

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, random-variables, expected-value, poisson-distribution

I have been struggling with some notation and cannot figure out where to find an in-depth explanation of how to approach this problem. Does anyone know any references or specific topics I need to study to really get a handle on this?

Just to be clear, this is homework, but I am not sure what exactly the notation means/ what I should be doing to solve it.

$X_r$ is a Poisson random variable with intensity rate $\frac{1}{r^2}$.
I need to figure out $E[\sum_{r=1}^{\infty}{rX_r}]$.
My teacher's "hint" is to use the Monotone Convergence Theorem, but that theorem is written as follows:
$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \int{f_n} d\mu = \int{\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty f_n} d\mu}$.

I have several questions...
First, it seems this $\sum_{r=1}^{\infty}{rX_r}$ should converge to a Poisson R.V.
But how do I determine what it converges to? When calculating expected value we need to use the probability measure function, but here we have many different ones (one for each $rX_r$, right?).
Am I supposed to figure out the what the $rX_r$ converge to and use that Poisson's probability function to find the expected value? (right side of the monotone convergence theorem).

Just for clarity the integrals in the chapter are all Lebesgue integrals, and this is my first exposure to them.

I am just very confused and do not know how to understand this.
I thought it would be like so:
$E[\sum_{r=1}^{\infty}{rX_r}] = \sum_{r=1}^{\infty}{E[rX_r]} = \sum_{r=1}^{\infty}{rE[X_r]} =  \sum_{r=1}^{\infty}{r \frac{1}{r^2}} =  \sum_{r=1}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{r}} = \infty  $.

But this diverges, so I do not think this is correct. I am rather confused. Is the notation my Professor used confusing, or am I just missing something fundamental? Please give me advice and point me in the right direction. Thank you so much!!

Comment: What's the relationship between the index of the sum $i$ and $r$? Are they supposed to be the same? If so, yes, $\infty$ is the answer, and your professor wants you to use monotone convergence to justify exchanging the expectation and the sum.

Comment: Oh I apologize. It should say $\sum_{r=1}^{\infty} rX_r$. I will edit it in just as second. However, it was stated in the problem that $\sum_{r=1}^{\infty} rX_r < \infty$ with probability 1. (Shouldn't this also be false? It was stated as being true. It was in the prior homework assignment using the Cantelli lemma, but I did not manage to prove it. )

Comment: A random variable can be finite almost surely and still have infinite expected value! For example a Cauchy random variable has this property: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_distribution

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Oh I see, thank you! I will try do as you suggest and use Monotone Convergence to justify this. Do you have any recommended readings (books, etc) or topics you think I should brush up on? Thank you for all your help.